# Parse Debian package version with C#

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, debian

On Linux from command line I can print Debian package version like this

```
dpkg-deb -I ./mypackage.deb
```

How can I do exactly the same in C# (.NET Core)?

I need the code to be platform independent (Windows, Linux).

What I understand from file format description is that I need to unzip this package file as [ar format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)). According to Wiki this format has not been standardized and there are several variants. I hope that there is some existing library, so I don't need to reinvent wheel. Then it is simply unzip and parsing text file which is called [control file](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/debian-dir-overview.html).

Comment: As far as I know, 7zip can handle this Ar format, check [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html). Also, maybe looking the sources of this [github](https://github.com/qmfrederik/dotnet-packaging) may also be helpful.